# wordpress function with custom database

Tags: database, wordpress

I am writing a WordPress plugin.

In one program, I capture the WordPress user id and write it to a file in a custom database.

Another program connects to the custom database, retrieves multiple rows having the user id:

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
$sql = "SELECT ...";  
$prep = $connection->prepare($sql);
```

and tries to access the wordpress function after retrieving each record:

```
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
```

As soon as the `get_userdata` function is executed, the programs dies.

Do I need to connect to the wordpress database?
If so, how?

Comment: ps. the SELECT and retrieval takes place in a php public function.

Comment: "the programs dies." > A concrete error message would be more helpful.

Comment: When I "inspected" the screen output, the only error was "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null ..."   This was due to a <div> statement that was not found because the program stopped and it never got that far in the program. When I commented out the get_userdata line of code, the program was fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Why you have made database connection manually this way as you can able to use global variable "global $wpdb;" and then able to write query based on "$wpdb".

Second thing, you might declare that $user_id variable as global, so can access it globally in file or you should define in functions.php file and check for their availability.

Please let me know if any of this solution does not work for you with details.

Comment: This application may be modified for Joomla or other CMS. So I'd prefer to code it to be as generic as possible.

Comment: How can a WordPress plugin be used by another CMS? I think you are facing a similar question like me a few weeks ago: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/377033/using-framework-wordpress-functions-in-layered-architecture

Comment: What I mean is, I am writing it for WP now, but may make modifications at a later date, to run on Joomla